# “doesn’t it”/“don’t they” with “every” as a determiner

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, quantifiers, question-tags, distributive-determiners

Which of the two is correct: “Every cell phone does that, doesn’t it?” or “Every cell phone does that, don’t they?”

Comment: "Every" is a distributive determiner as reflected by the fact that it selects a singular 'head', hence "Every student is here", not *"Every students are here". "Cell phone" has singular "phone" as head, so singular tag "doesn't it?" is the one you want; (note that you can say "All the cell phones do that, don't they?)

Comment: @BillJ Could you maybe convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Every cell phone does that, doesn’t it? **or** Every cell phone does that, don’t they?*

"Every" is a distributive determiner as reflected in the fact that it selects a singular 'head', hence "Every **student** is here", not *"Every **students** are here".

"Cell phone" has singular "phone" as head, so singular tag "doesn't it?" is the one you want. Note that you can use a plural tag with "all": ***All*** the cell phones do that, don't they?.

Comment: -1: So you would recommend *Every girl does that, doesn't she?* That sounds really wrong, and I think it sounded wrong before the move towards gender neutrality in English.

Comment: @PeterShor Must be a US/UK split there. Sounds fine to me.